# Question about a paper by Berry and Tabor about periodic orbit theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiclassical

I have a question on the following paper: https://michaelberryphysics.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/berry051.pdf

In this paper Berry and Tabor developed a method for finding the quantum mechanical density of states in the semi-classical approximation. Starting from equation (10)
$$ n_{\vec{M}}= \int \mathrm{d}^nI \ \delta(E-H(\vec{I}))\ e^{(2\pi i /\hbar)\vec{M}\cdot\vec{I}}$$ they perform a transformation from $\vec{I} \rightarrow \vec{\xi}$ in a way that $\xi_0$ measures the perpendicular distance of a point $\vec{I}$ from the energy surface $E=H(\vec{I})$ and the remaining coordinates $(\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_{n-1})$ parametrize the energy surface. By doing so they end up with equation (11)

$$ n_{\vec{M}} = \int \mathrm{d}^{n-1}\xi e^{(2\pi i /\hbar)\vec{M}\cdot\vec{I}} \int \mathrm{d}\xi_0 \frac{\delta(\xi_0)}{|\partial H/\partial\xi_0|}.$$ My question is, shouldn't there be a Jacobian? According to Fritz Haake in his book 'Quantum Signatures of Chaos' the Jacobian is contained in the measure $\mathrm{d}^{n-1} \xi$ in equation (11). However, neither in the original paper nor in the book the end result (equation (20) in the paper) contains this Jacobian. I really don't see what this is about.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible the Jacobian is "hidden" in the $\text{d}^{n-1}\xi$? What I mean is, often we will write things like $\text{d}^3x$ and understand that this means, in spherical coordinates, $r^2 \sin\theta \text{d}r \text{d}\theta \text{d}\phi$.

Comment: Yes that is what Fritz Haake says. But if you check the result (equation 20) in the paper there is no Jacobian. So it seems that it cancels out somewhere?!